# Find all functions $f:\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(x+1)=f(x)+1$

Tags: functions

The function $f(x)=x+c$ seems trivial but I thought whether it is the only function.

I tried to used induction but I'm not sure how to do it for $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: $f(x)=x+a$ also works (for all $a\in\mathbb{Q}$). Unless I'm wrong these should be the only solutions

Comment: In a second thought. It may have more solutions, for instance you can take $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $f(x)=x+1$ otherwise. It also satisfies this equation.

Comment: **Any** function defined on $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ can be extended to whole $\mathbb{Q}$ in a way that satisfies your equality.

Comment: Are there any non linear polynomial solutions ?

Comment: Please show HOW...

Comment: @attepl There are no other polynomial solutions. But there are non-polynomial solutions as well.

Comment: @freakish: that should be $[0,1)\cap\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @attepl The immediate consequence of your property is that $f(x)=f(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)+\lfloor x\rfloor$ for any $x$. And since $x-\lfloor x\rfloor\in [0,1)$ then here you go - all values of $f$ are fully determined by values on $[0,1)$. Also no polynomial of degree higher then $1$ satsifies this. That's because $f(x+1)-f(x)\neq 1$ for sufficiently big $x$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given *any* function $g:\Bbb Q\cap[0,1)\to\Bbb Q$, the function

$$f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor + g(\{x\})$$

satisfies your condition. (Here $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the integral part of $x$ and $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$.)

And indeed any $f$ that satisfies your condition must be of this form.